# Does Firebase Auth (JS) support offline signin attempts?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So my question might sound strange, but seeing as there is already offline support for Firestore, it might make sense to allow users that have been "cached (meaning logged in before, while online)" to login while offline.

Basically, we're worried about a scenario where the user does a `.signout()` after having lost the internet connection and is then unable to log back in.

Can such a scenario be handled atm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a supported scenario.  If a user signs out, their authentication token is deleted from local storage.  A new auth token can't be obtained again while offline, because there's no way to validate their identity.